# Best way to transfer staging files with changes to prod?

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have two directories in my www folder - html and staging. My domain has staging.*.com linked to the staging directory and *.com linked to the html directory.

My question is simple. Is there a simple way to make changes in the staging directory and then when I want to transfer those changes to prod, just copy over the files?

I'm running Ubuntu on an AWS instance.

Right now I'm dragging the files manually in an FTP transfer app but this really isn't sustainable long term.

Comment: This appears to be an unusual setup. Are you using the Staging server as developer machine? Are you using git already or you're asking how to incorporate it to your workflow?

Comment: Take a look at revision control systems. No serious project comes along without. Dominant today is `git` and it actually is well suited to smaller, private projects due to its distributed principle. So create a git project, import your files, that gives you a full documented history of all changes. Which can be easily replayed to all cloned locations by simply "pulling" the changes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Im not using git at all as is. The staging server is the same as the prod server, just in different directories. Once points to staging.site.com and the other is just site.com. Can git help me transfer my files from the staging directory to the prod directory. Is there a better way to do all of this? I tried getting nginx running on my local machine but failed.

Comment: Git is certainly a way to move files around. You just need to pull changes from the upstream repository.